# Linux: How to output directory size as a number excluding directory path

Tags: linux

How do output the directory size in Linux?

I am currently using "du /root/test" but I get the following result:

754 /root/test

I need to output only the number like:

754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du /root/test | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your directory may have subdirectories, use -s for summary:

```
du -s /root/test |awk '{print $1}'
```